# jQuery datepicker not displayed

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to use jQuery datepicker but it's not working as expected.

Here is my fiddle:
  http://jsfiddle.net/ovj3y4du/

HTML:

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

Comment: If you are using the jqueryui datepiker, you forgot to import it. <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work since it is the simplest way of creating a datepicker.

What I see as the problem is that you do not have the `jquery-ui.js` file imported in your script.

See your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ovj3y4du/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing reference of JQuery ui. I added this cdn in the updated jsfiddle:

> https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js

Nothing changed in your code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

Live Demo:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ovj3y4du/2/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

you must add a jquery UI library. here is the update, look at external resource, i just add a jqueryUI library

```
jsfiddle.net/ovj3y4du/4/
```